# Expected type warning python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have

```
class Action:
```

and the

```
class ModifyFileAction (Action):
```

I have the next if statement:

```
action_type = type(action)
if action_type == ModifyFileAction:
    self.execute_modify_file_action(action)
```

and the method:

```
def execute_modify_file_action(self, action: ModifyFileAction):
```

In the third code block (when I call `execute_modify_file_action`)I have the next warning:

```
Expected type 'ModifyFileAction', got 'Action' instead
```

UPD. Some more code:

```
class Action:
    def __init__(self, action_id):
        self._action_id = action_id

    @property
    def action_id(self):
        return self._action_id

class ModifyFileAction (Action):
    def __init__(self, action_id, params):
        super().__init__(action_id)
        self._path, self._hash, self._prev_action_id = params

    @property
    def path(self):
        return self._path

    @property
    def hash(self):
        return self._hash

    @property
    def prev_action_id(self):
        return self._prev_action_id

class FileSystem:
    def __init__(self):
        self._root = Folder(None, 'root', 0)
        self._bulks = 1

    def execute(self, action: Action):
        action_type = type(action)
        if action_type == RemoveFolderAction:
            pass
        if action_type == RemoveFileAction:
            self.execute_remove_file_action(action)
        if action_type == ModifyFileAction:
            self.execute_modify_file_action(action)
        if action_type == CreateFolderAction:
            pass
        if action_type == RenameFolderAction:
            pass
        if action_type == RenameFileAction:
            self.execute_rename_file_action(action)

    def execute_modify_file_action(self, action: ModifyFileAction):
        file = self.create_file_if_not_exists(action.path, self._bulks)
        file.add_version(action.prev_action_id, self._bulks + 1, action.action_id, action.hash)
```

How should I cast `action` variable in order to avoid the warning?

Comment: What is the "third code block"?

Comment: @ScottHunter ```action_type = type(action)
if action_type == ModifyFileAction:
    self.execute_modify_file_action(action)```

Comment: Show how you create the `action` object.

Comment: @ScottHunter I receive it as an argument: ```def execute(self, action: Action):```

Comment: So you are passing an `Action` instance, not a `ModifyFileAction` instance. The error message is consistent with this.

Comment: @mhawke But I check whether its type equals ```ModifyFileAction ```

Comment: From the random snippets of code it's difficult to know what is going on. Why are you checking the types explicitly? In which class and method is the `action_type = type(action)....` code in? Could you post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227407/discussion-between---and-mhawke).

Comment: Why don't you implement `execute_modify_file_action()` in your `ModifyFileAction` class? That's where it belongs. Then you don't need to look at types to manually dispatch the function call.

Comment: @mhawke I consider that FileSystem knows how to execute the actions and Action classes are just "notifications". It seems to me that it is more logical from the point of OOP view.